# Embarcadero C++ Builder data structure that can store different complex data types

Tags: c++, variant, tvalue

I am using C++ Builder 10.2.3.
I need to store from simple to complex data types, and restore them:

```
int
float
.
.
std::vector<int>
std::vector<br::Transform*>() /* Transform is a user created class*/
etc...
```

I already tried Variant and TValue. Unfortunately they cannot store and restore complex data like `std::vector<br::Transform*>()`. And I cannot create new Variant types for each of them as I explained in a previous question. There are too many of complex data types!

Any hint?

Comment: I was just thinking about boost libraries.
I don't know what they can do.
Can they be a solution?

Comment: In C world, you can use a simply ```void*```, if the only common abstraction of these type are that they absolutely need some storage.

Comment: I don't think that it will work. Because I have to define typedef with maps and vectors. In the same way, I am trying to use templates instead to see if I can replace all of them.

Comment: Have you tried `std::variant` yet? It won't work in the classic Borland compiler, but it will in the Clang compilers.

Comment: It seems to me that you told me previously that it is bugged?
And can it store and restore complex types like std::vector<br::Transform*> ?

Comment: The comment I posted first. I know that std::variant in C++ Builder is bugged.
But what about boost::variant? Did somebody tried that before?
This will help me safe time.